# Electron error 'could not find a good path to install to'

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

So I have built an electron app with electron builder. So after installing it on serveral computers, only 3 out of 7 computers are working. I have no idea why... Googling towards this error doesnt really give me a better understanding.

But now for a lot of other pc's I get the "Could not find a good path to isntall to" error. This are my dependencies:

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "description": "spa app with nfc tags.",
  "build": {
    "appId": "xx.xxxxxx",
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.business"
    },
    "files": [
      "*.js",
      "app/renderer/assets/css/app.css",
      "build"
    ],
    "nsis" : {
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": true,
      "runAfterFinish": false,
      "createDesktopShortcut": true,
      "createStartMenuShortcut" : true
    }
  },
  "keywords": [
    "electron",
    "nfc",
    "nfc-pcsc",
    "vue"
  ],
  "nodeGypRebuild": "true",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/pokusew/electron-vue-nfc#readme",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/pokusew/electron-vue-nfc/issues"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": {
    "name": "Martin Endler",
    "url": "https://github.com/pokusew"
  },
  "main": "main.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/pokusew/electron-vue-nfc.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn run build-main && yarn run build-renderer && powershell -Command Copy-Item ./app/renderer/assets/css/app.css -Destination ./build && powershell -Command Copy-Item ./icon.ico -Destination ./build",
    "build-main": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node -r @babel/register ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config webpack.config.main.prod.js --progress --profile --colors",
    "build-renderer": "rimraf build && cross-env NODE_ENV=production node -r @babel/register ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config webpack.config.renderer.prod.js --progress --profile --colors",
    "hot-server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node -r @babel/register ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.renderer.dev.js",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w nfc-pcsc",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production electron ./",
    "start-hot": "cross-env HOT=1 NODE_ENV=development electron -r @babel/register -r @babel/polyfill ./main.development",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "pack-win": "electron-builder --win --x64",
    "post-install": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0-beta.46",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "electron-log": "^2.2.14",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "nfc-pcsc": "^0.6.2",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-config": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-momentjs": "^0.1.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuetify": "^1.0.17",
    "windows": "^0.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.46",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0-beta.46",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.46",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0-beta.46",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.0-beta.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^20.15.1",
    "electron-debug": "^1.5.0",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.7.3",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "vue-devtools": "^3.1.9",
    "vue-loader": "^15.0.9",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
    "webpack": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2"
  }
}
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.. If you need more info please ask

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json main is pointing to 'main.js' instead of 'app/main/index.js'.
Change that entry and try builing your application again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that setting is correct we have a main.js too... 

I tried to change it i get a application entry file " app/main/inde.js"  in the blabala seems like a wrong configuration..